# How to trigger Google Cloud Build on GitHub ref/pull/*/merge branch events

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

As far as I can tell there are two ways of triggering a Google Cloud Build on a GitHub repo:

1. All pull requests are automatically built
2. Define a trigger than runs when a branch is changed

An unmerged GitHub pull request has 2 refs as shown here:

```
$ git ls-remote
From git@github.com:user/repo
1680161331c0a0ebcf59fb1ef2f4dbe27b857418    HEAD
9e1d427bfcd97d8ac2eda7661cc8a21da2355d19    refs/heads/if_deps
ee8328eb1e5fa38c9cc39c86d8b0896c9eaec73c    refs/heads/mcmc-fixes
1680161331c0a0ebcf59fb1ef2f4dbe27b857418    refs/heads/master
94d3a40412aff060a2a820d164dfd52050cac192    refs/pull/1/head
9e1d427bfcd97d8ac2eda7661cc8a21da2355d19    refs/pull/2/head
ccb44a8c12ed9d79e76551e7876892c9e87de032    refs/pull/2/merge
ee8328eb1e5fa38c9cc39c86d8b0896c9eaec73c    refs/pull/3/head
f9928f924698042939008e8526094662b7f44125    refs/pull/3/merge
```

- PR #1 has been merged and only has `refs/pull/1/head`
- PRs #2 and #3 have not been merged and `refs/pull/2/merge` also exist

Unfortunately the automatic pull request trigger only builds the `refs/pull/*/head` ref and not the `refs/pull/*/merge` ref. It is more important to build `refs/pull/*/merge` to prove that the pull request can be safely merged into master.

So I am trying to define a trigger to run on `refs/pull/*/merge`

As far as I can tell Google Cloud Build triggers only match GitHub refs of the form `refs/heads/<regex>` though:

[image: Cloud Builder Triggers]

Is it possible to trigger a build when a `refs/pull/*/merge` branch is changed?

Answer (score 1):

I also tested it and it's true that builds are not triggered for `refs/pull/*/merge`.

There's a [Feature Request on the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119662038) about this, so it might get implemented in the future.